# How to: If values present, output: "Y" If null, output: "N"

Tags: bi-publisher

Most of the question is in the title.

If there is a value present in the database (doesn't matter what it is as long as it's not null), I want the output to say "Y" or "Yes" --it doesn't matter. I just need it to say what I want it to. I don't care what the value us so long as there is, in fact a value.

I already know how to rename all nulls to whatever I want. It's mostly the above question I can't figure out. And for those of you who do answer there, where are you finding this stuff? The manual is mostly useless and so are all the youtube videos on this program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the value in your database is null then you can do this in your data model:

coalesce(YourAttribute,'N')as name.

In case your attribute is not null and you want to display 'Y',
go to your BI Publisher Layout,select Data Field tab and choose Highlight from conditional formating.There, set the data field, operator(is equal to) and value "Y" 
[this image indicates where is the conditional formating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AysPw.png)

Hope this helps